# ColdFusion 2016 change location of served files to /var/www/html

Tags: apache, coldfusion, httpd.conf, coldfusion-2016

I have ColdFusion 2016 installed in CentOS 7 and I have Apache (httpd) installed and ColdFusion configured to use it. The installation path and the location of the wwwroot folder is standard: `/opt/coldfusion2016/cfusion/wwwroot/` When I put a file inside this folder **wwwroot** `/opt/coldfusion2016/cfusion/wwwroot/index.cfm` httpd reads it and I can see that any ColdFusion code in the file is interpreted well by apache.

```
index.cfm
<cfset name="John">
<cfoutput> Hello #name# ! </cfoutput>
```

http://192.168.X.X/index.cfm shows Hello John!

I did not create any special virtualhost yet so my question is: How do I make ColdFusion reads files from `/var/www/html` instead of `/opt/coldfusion2016/cfusion/wwwroot`
Is this done via ColdFusion administration or via apache httpd configuration?

Comment: Am I asking a complicated question please?

Comment: It is configured through your web server (apache httpd for you) and also ColdFusion web server configuration tool.  See information and steps here - [Connect to web servers](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/web-server-management.html)

Comment: Hi, I don't think you understood my request. If I follow the link you sent, they ask to run this command  ./wsconfig  -ws Apache -dir <path to apache conf> -vhost <vhost server name> so I run it as ./wsconfig  -ws Apache -dir /etc/httpd/conf -site mysite.local (-vhost no logger exists in CF2016 apparently as it gives an error) The output is : This web server is already configured for ColdFusion. Am I missing something here please? By the way CF still servers files from wwwroot when I go to mysite.local/sample.cfc

Comment: More information specifically for ColdFusion 2016 [Configuring connectors with Apache Virtual Hosts in ColdFusion (2016 release)](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2016/10/configuring-connectors-with-apache-virtual-hosts-in-coldfusion-2016-release/)

Comment: As I stated in my comment the -vhosts gives an error as it is no longer a supported command so how do I add all vhosts then?

Comment: Read the last comment I posted. That article is from Adobe and specific to CF 2016. The command examples do not include vhost option.  `sudo ./wsconfig -ws Apache  -bin /usr/sbin/httpd -script /usr/sbin/apachectl -dir /etc/httpd/conf/ -v`  -- THERE IS MORE WORK TO DO AFTER RUNNING THAT COMMAND --

Comment: _I deleted my previous comment to avoid confusion_

Comment: Yes I run the command successfully, then I went to my domain conf file located at /etc/httpd/conf.d/mydomain.local and added  JKMountFile path entry to it then restarted apache. I see no erros but CF is still not finding my file in /var/www/html it says File not found: /hello.cfm if I type mydomain.local/hello.cfm even if the file is in /var/www/html which is the DocumentRoot in that config. What am I missing please?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to help you.  Check this  https://serverfault.com/q/984178/135433

Comment: The 404 was a ColdFusion error page not Apache 404 for missing files. No problem, thank for your help anyway.

Comment: Hi, I'm back here to correct my issue. I fixed it because it was permission issues due to the fact that I was using a shared folder between Linux and windows via virtual box so I was sharing the www folder and with vbox as user it created a conflict to I just removed the sharing folder and used ssh to access files instead of sharing them and it worked.

Comment: Instead of adding a comment you should post that as an answer.  It is okay to answer your own question.  Just be sure to include details on how you resolved the issue.  Thanks for coming back here and doing so.